# How to bound spinner with listarray object

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
ArrayList<DataCCHeading>CC1=new ArrayList<DataCCHeading>();
ArrayList<DataCCHeading>CC2=new ArrayList<DataCCHeading>();

ArrayList<DataCCHeading>hd=new ArrayList<DataCCHeading>(result);
for (DataCCHeading dataCCHeading : hd) {
    if(dataCCHeading.Ownername==TAG_CC1HeadingData){
        CC1.add(dataCCHeading);
    }
    else if(dataCCHeading.Ownername==TAG_CC2HeadingData){
        CC2.add(dataCCHeading);
    }
}

ArrayAdapter<DataCCHeading>adaptercc1=new ArrayAdapter<DataCCHeading>(TimeClockDashBoard.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,CC1);
adaptercc1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
myCC1Spinner.setAdapter(adaptercc1);

ArrayAdapter<DataCCHeading>adaptercc2=new ArrayAdapter<DataCCHeading>(TimeClockDashBoard.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,CC2);
adaptercc2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
myCC2spinner.setAdapter(adaptercc2);
```

Data is not displayed... DataCCHeading is the class...

```
public class DataCCHeading {
    String Code;
    String Description;
    String Ownername;

    public DataCCHeading(String Code, String Description,String owner) {
        this.Code = Code;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.Ownername=owner;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Code;
    }

    public String GetDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public String Ownername()
    {
        return Ownername;
    }
}
```

I want to display only description in spinner. Spinner does not show any data. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but in Java you **cannot** use `==` to compare Strings:

```
// This will not work! (Most of the time)
if(dataCCHeading.Ownername==TAG_CC1HeadingData)
```

You **must** use String.equals() to compare exact matches:

```
if(dataCCHeading.Ownername.equals(TAG_CC1HeadingData)){
    CC1.add(dataCCHeading);
}
else if(dataCCHeading.Ownername.equals(TAG_CC2HeadingData)){
    CC2.add(dataCCHeading);
}
else {
    Log.w("Warning!", "Data for Spinners does not match CC1 or CC2 HeadingData");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayListCC1=new ArrayList();

ArrayListhd=new ArrayList(result);

```
     for (DataCCHeading dataCCHeading : hd) {
         if(dataCCHeading.Ownername==TAG_CC1HeadingData)
         {
             CC1.add(dataCCHeading);

         }
    }
```

ArrayAdapteradaptercc1=new ArrayAdapter(TimeClockDashBoard.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                   ,CC1);
 adaptercc1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               myCC1Spinner.setAdapter(adaptercc1);